# performance impact of default value set on table's column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

if a table have default value on a column for e.g.

```
    create table emp
(
       flag    smallint default 1
)
```

so is there any impact of this default column in bulk import , if I am not using in insert statement.

Comment: Do you want a default value or not?

Comment: yes I want a default value , just want to know is there any impact on bulk insert and only one row insert , or using this column in insert statement

Comment: If without default it would store NULL values for that column then there will be a tiny cost because each row will be two bytes larger. But I wouldn't expect it to be noticable.

Comment: It's got to write either a `1` or a `null` when creating a row either way so I doubt there would be much impact from an IO perspective, and  performance wise that's typically the lion's share of the work.

Answer (score 7):

According to the docs:

**Before 11:**

> Adding a column with a default requires updating each row of the table (to store the new column value). However, if no default is specified, PostgreSQL is able to avoid the physical update. So if you intend to fill the column with mostly nondefault values, it's best to add the column with no default, insert the correct values using UPDATE, and then add any desired default as described below.

[source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-alter.html)

**11 and after:**

> From PostgreSQL 11, adding a column with a constant default value no longer means that each row of the table needs to be updated when the ALTER TABLE statement is executed. Instead, the default value will be returned the next time the row is accessed, and applied when the table is rewritten, making the ALTER TABLE very fast even on large tables. However, if the default value is volatile (e.g., clock_timestamp()) each row will need to be updated with the value calculated at the time ALTER TABLE is executed. To avoid a potentially lengthy update operation, particularly if you intend to fill the column with mostly nondefault values anyway, it may be preferable to add the column with no default, insert the correct values using UPDATE, and then add any desired default as described below.

[source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-alter.html)

Comment: That's about _adding_ a column to an existing table, not create brand new table.

Comment: this is pleasant stuff

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look into the source for the generator/planner/optimizer/rewriter
( postgresql/src/backend/rewrite/rewriteHandler.c around line#1112, function `build_column_default()` ) :

The default value(or function, e.g. for serials) is fetched from the catalogs and added **once** to the query tree. So, the `DEFAULT` may even be **more** efficient than fetching *separate* values for all affected rows from one of the tables in query.

But you would have to measure the difference to be sure.